# 'Cannot find module' TypeScript after VS 2015 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have two TypeScript files in my project

In first file I wrote

```
import moduleB = require('moduleB');
class ModuleA {
    //some logic
}
```

In second file

```
/// <amd-module name="moduleB" />

class ModuleB {
    //some logic
}
export = ModuleB
```

I build my ts files via gulp

```
gulp.src('./JScripts/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(srcmaps.init())
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: false,
            target: 'ES5',
            module: 'amd'
        })).js
```

All works fine, and intellisense was fine in VS 2015 Update 2. After update on VS 2015 Update 3 all works same - fine, but intellisense goes crazy.
There is an error 'Cannot find module 'moduleB'' for first file

As far as I can understand I should check my **.tslint** file because I don't use VS Typescript Build (I use Gulp instead)

How can I fix this error?